# How do I change key bindings for org-mode agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda

`org-mode` agenda view has a bunch of commands accessible with a single key press.

E.g. typing `b` moves backward in time to display earlier dates, and typing `t` brings up a dialog to change the TODO state of the item.

I would like to redefine `t` to toggle between `TODO` and `DONE` without any dialog, and also redefine `b` to reschedule a task at focus to the next week.

How can those built-in commands be redefined?

Comment: See the [manual re: key-bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html).

Comment: `(require 'org-agenda) (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "t" 'butterfly)`  You only need the require statement one time at the outset before redefining the bindings.

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate, but I don't have the time to look it up. (This question also seems to be a bit confused. Is it about changing key bindings (per the title) or about redefining commands (per the last line)?)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've read in the docs about adding new keys to the `C-c a <key>` scheme, but found nothing about the `org-agenda-mode-map`

Comment: Consider revising the question to ask just one question, instead of three different questions.  The `butterfly` example above is sufficient to teach you how to redefine keys for the org-agenda view.  The other two questions should each be a separate thread -- i.e., thread number one is the butterfly question/answer; thread number two is creating a simple toggle between todo/done; thread number three is how to reschedule a task for next week.  Please be certain to **Google** a bit and see if there are already threads that answer your question -- because that is what we will do before answering.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that in two steps:

1. define a function to change the state
2. map the function to <kbd>b</kbd> in `org-agenda-mode`

## Define a function to change the state

```lisp
(defun my/org-agenda-todo-done ()
  (interactive)
  (org-agenda-todo 'done))
```

[`org-todo`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.1.13/lisp/org.el#L12370) and [`org-agenda-todo`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.1.13/lisp/org-agenda.el#L8839) takes arguments. Of which, you can define the state.

## Map the function to <kbd>b</kbd> in `org-agenda-mode`

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
                  (local-set-key (kbd "b") 'my/org-agenda-todo-done)))
```

Bind the function to the key of your choice.  Make sure to add your key to the `org-agenda-mode-map`.  `local-set-key` on the hook will do.

Note that <kbd>b</kbd> is mapped to `org-agenda-earlier` in default. If you don't want to lose it, remap to another key.

Comment: did you mean to write "b" instead of "d" in the source block?

Comment: Yes. Thanks.  Fixed.