# Remapping keys in org mode agenda view

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda

I currently trying to remap my org mode agenda keymap in Spacemacs for `org-agenda-next-item` and `org-agenda-previous-item`. In the agenda view I like to map the functions to `k` for next-line and `l` for previous-line.

I already tested different approaches like:

```
  (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "k") 'org-agenda-next-item)
  (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "l") 'org-agenda-previous-item)
```

The result of this one is:
`Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-agenda-mode-map`. And it doesn't matter if I put the key mappings into `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook` or `(with-eval-after-load 'org` environments..

Or this one (source: [How do I change key bindings for org-mode agenda view?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/how-do-i-change-key-bindings-for-org-mode-agenda-view)):

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
                  (local-set-key (kbd "k") 'org-agenda-next-item)))
```

This runs without an error, but the remapping of the key `k` does not take place.

I also checked the command `describe-keymap` to search for the correct keymap register. But it seems, that `org-agenda-mode-map` is the correct one.

Is there another approach, which might work? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook (lambda ()
      (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "k" 'org-agenda-next-item)))` works for me.

Comment: @NickD: I tested it but it does not work.. May be it is the wrong keymap?

Comment: No, the keymap is correct. What does `C-h c k` say when you invoke it in the agenda buffer (first, without the above hook in place, then with it in place, killing the agenda buffer in between and recreating it)? I get `org-agenda-capture` in the first case,  `org-agenda-next-item` in the second.